# Fetch all the files modified in last days

Tags: python-3.x

I need to get all files of a folder using python for the last N days. While using the code:

```
 result = glob.iglob('*.zip')
 latest_file = max(result, key=os.path.getctime)
```

This provides only the last modified file. I have a directory that contains multiple files as below and to extract all of them is consuming long time.

```
multilog-2022-07-08-04:24:07.zip
multilog-2022-07-08-05:40:10.zip
multilog-2022-07-09-04:24:07.zip
```

This is my current code where it extracts all zip file in the directory. I need to get only the files that are modified in the last 2 days.

```
all_zip = glob.glob('*.zip')
for i in all_zip:
    print(i)
```

Comment: A warning: `getctime` does not have a stable definition across OSes (it means original creation date on Windows, and last metadata change data on UNIX-likes). You usually want to use `getmtime` (which is last modification time, and honestly makes more sense than creation time even on Windows; a file which is truncated and rebuilt from scratch has the same creation time on Windows, but accurately updates the modified time in the same way on all OSes).

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an if statement to only print based on the key you were using before?

```
import time

all_zip = glob.glob('*.zip')
for i in all_zip:
  if (float(os.path.getmtime(i)) > time.time() - 172800):
    print(i)
```

Note that `time.time()` returns the current time in epoch format, and `172800` is the number of seconds in two days.

**Edit 1:** Another possible (although not necessarily better or as portable) means of doing this could involve leveraging a bash command: `find . -name '*.zip' -mtime -2`

**Edit 2:** Changed `getctime` to `getmtime` in accordance with ShadowRanger's comment.